# Joining 3 tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables namely: `user`, `special_order`, `corp_order`.

I want a result where it can display all orders placed by a user in both order tables.

My SQL statement is:

```
SELECT 
    u.user_id,
    c.user_id,
    s.user_id
FROM
    corp_user u
JOIN 
    special_order s ON s.user_id = u.user_id
JOIN 
    corp_orders c ON c.user_id = u.user_id;
```

which is returning unnecessary data.

Comment: do you mean both tables, or either table?

Comment: This post will probably help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join

Comment: @jdow both the tables. A user have some order placed in `special_orders` and some orders in `corp_orders`

Comment: You probably are better off having 2 separate queries as I presume that there is no relationship between `special` and `corporate` orders

Comment: Please post expected result and actual result as text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is all orders, regardless of whether they are special orders or coprporate orders. Decide what columns you want from each corp_user table, and matching columns for orders from each order table and then do two separate queries that are linked by `UNION ALL`. (You want `UNION ALL`, not `UNION` because otherwise if there are exact matches in all fields, the duplicates would be eliminated.

Example for illustration:

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    s.order_id
FROM
    corp_user u 
    INNER JOIN special_order s on u.user_id = s.user_id
UNION ALL
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    c.order_id
FROM
    corp_user u 
    INNER JOIN corp_order c on u.user_id = c.user_id
```

Note: fields must match exactly - not necessarily in names, but in position. Names from first query will be used.